# How to configure ESLint plugin for VSCode to fix on save but not highlight errors?

Tags: vscode-eslint

I want it to fix lint errors when I save a file but not highlight them with red lines while I'm editing the file. I only want it to highlight syntax errors and typescript errors. Seems, reasonable, no?

I feel like this should be straightforward, and it works this way for another project that doesn't have `"eslint.format.enable": true` to enable rules from an `.eslintrc.json` file in an external package, but I don't see a way to get it to work for this other project that has this setting set. How do I accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: No I didn't find a way to do this